# How to show that $\theta=\sum_{j=1}^n f_j\cdot (\alpha_j\circ \Phi)$ for some $f_j\in C^\infty(B^\prime)$ and $\alpha_j\in\Gamma(E)$?

Tags: differential-geometry, vector-bundles

Let $\pi:E\longrightarrow B$ be a vector bundle, $\Phi:B^\prime\longrightarrow B$ and $\theta:B^\prime\longrightarrow E$ be smooth maps such that $$\pi\circ \theta=\Phi.$$ How can I show $\theta$ has the form $$\theta=\sum_{j=1}^n f_j\cdot (\alpha_j\circ \Phi),$$ for some $f_j\in C^\infty(B^\prime)$ and $\alpha_j\in \Gamma(E)$? You can add hypothesis in order to use partition of unity if you wish.

Thanks.

Comment: This doesn't seem correct as it stands. What if $\Phi$ is a constant map (and the rank of $E$ is at least $2$)?

Comment: I'll think about your point. Anyway, the condition $\pi\circ \theta=\Phi$ ensures that $(\theta, \textrm{id}_{B^\prime})\in \Gamma(\Phi^*(E))$ and we have an isomorphism $C^\infty(B^\prime)\otimes_{C^\infty(B)}\Gamma(E)\longrightarrow \Gamma(\Phi^*(E))$ given by $f\otimes \alpha\longmapsto (f\cdot (\alpha\circ \Phi), \textrm{id}_{B^\prime})$ so $\theta$ should have that form, but I'd like a constructive approach...